# grouping by category, counting, sum, and dividing at the same time - R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
> set.seed(100)
> df <- data.frame(X1 = sample(c(1:7, NA), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 X2 = sample(c(1:7, NA), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 X3 = sample(c(1:7, NA), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 YY = sample(c("a","b"), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
   X1 X2 X3 YY
1   3  5  5  a
2   3 NA  6  b
3   5  3  5  a
4   1  4  6  b
5   4  7  4  b
6   4  6  2  b
7   7  2  7  a
8   3  3 NA  b
9   5  3  5  b
10  2  6  3  a
```

Where the final output is this:

```
YY   X1     X2    X3
 a  -0.25  -0.25  0
 b  -0.83  -0.2   0
```

The formula for each percentage is:

(`counts of c(6,7)` - `counts of c(1,2,3,4)`) / `counts of c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`. For example, to get the `-0.5` for `X1` and `a`:

```
Where the columns is `X1` and `YY = a`, then:
prom = counts of c(6,7) = 1 
detr = counts of c(1,2,3,4) = 4 
total = counts of c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) = 6 
The percentage is (prom - detr) / total = (1-4)/ 6 = -0.5
```

And I'm trying to achieve that output through a loop on each column (`X1,X2, and X3`) where, for each column:

```
 > table(df[,X1], df$YY)
    a b
  1 0 1
  2 1 0
  3 1 2
  4 0 2
  5 1 1
  7 1 0
```

And sum the respective counts for `a` and `b`. But I'm struggling to access this `table()` and, for each `YY`, sum the respective counts, rest them, and divide them by the total of counts. I was thinking to access the table and sum by criteria with `expss::sum_if()`, but I still don't figure out a way.

Is there a easier way to do it? Any idea?. I tried with dplyr also, but it seems more complicated when I have to group by category and counting, sum, and dividing per column and end with that small output.

Comment: **1)** Please use `set.seed()` when using functions like `sample`. **2)** Please explain it better. This, `(counts of c(6,7) - counts of c(1,2,3,4)) / counts of c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` is not clear to me

Comment: I developed a better example. For what is set.seed()?

Comment: `set.seed()` is to ensure reproducibility. The function `sample` will sample different values every time you run it, unless you set a seed

Comment: Generally speaking, NPS score is strictly identical to `mean(case_when(x %in% 1:4~ 1, x %in% 6:7 ~ -1, TRUE ~ 0))`. If you recode your raw scales to -1, 0, 1 then all further calculations will become much simpler. Additionally, you can easily make significance testing with t-tests between groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `YY` and then summarize every grouped column using the indicated function (expressed in formula notation).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(YY) %>%
  summarize_all(~ (sum(.x %in% 6:7) - sum(.x %in% 1:4)) / sum(.x %in% 1:7)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  YY       X1    X2    X3
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     -0.5     -1     0
2 b      0.25    -1    -1
```

Comment: It works! Thanks ! Can you explain how works there those summarize_all() and ungroup() a little bit?

Comment: (1) `summarize` (and `summarize_all`)  is used to reduce all the rows in the group to a single row using the aggregate function specified. (2) It's good form to match each `group_by` to an `ungroup`.  In this case you get the same result if the `ungroup` is omitted but in other cases if you omit the `ungroup` and then subsequently feed the output into a new pipeline then memory of the `group_by` will be passed on which could give unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a function `get_ratio` based on our formula

```
get_ratio <- function(x) {
  (sum(x %in% 6:7) - sum(x %in% 1:4))/sum(x %in% 1:7)
}
```

and now apply it for every group (`YY`)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(YY) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(X1:X3), get_ratio)

#    YY       X1     X2    X3
#   <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    a     -0.5     -1     0
#2    b      0.25    -1    -1
```

Comment: It gives me this error: Error in eval(variables_names, envir = envir, enclos = baseenv()) : object 'X1' not found. Why could it be?

Comment: @Chris Not sure. Do you have column with different name and not `X1`, `X2` ? Also make sure to apply the above command on your original `df` and not the `table`.

Comment: It was because I was using vars from expss. However, the values aren't right also. :/

Comment: I misread the last part. You wanted to divide by number of values which has `1:7`. Updated the function, should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this?

```
    NPS_count <- function(x, prom=c(6,7), detr=seq(1:4)) {
      case_when(x %in% prom ~ 1,
                x %in% detr ~ -1,
                TRUE ~ 0)
    }


    df %>% 
  group_by(YY) %>% 
  summarise(X1 = sum(NPS_count(X1))/n(),
            X2 = sum(NPS_count(X2))/n(),
            X3 = sum(NPS_count(X3))/n())
```

Comment: The structure of your output is what I'm looking for, but the values are not right :/

Comment: I see, you want to ignore '5' in your NPS

Comment: Just for prom and detr. It has to be included for the total :)

Comment: Same, the structure is good but the values are still not right. I have edited the example with a set.seed(100). The values of the final output showed above are the right ones.

Comment: This is strange.
My results for set.seed(100) are the same as in your question
  YY        X1     X2    X3
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     -0.25  -0.25      0
2 b     -0.833 -0.167     0